# Django deployment in Hostgator VPS - PHP and Python on same server - easyapache24 and mod-wsgi

Tags: django, apache, web-deployment, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

- I'm trying to run django using mod_wsgi module in easyapache4 on CentOS 7 VPS provided by Hostgator.

**PHP and Django on same server**

What I tried so far: created venv and project in `/home/user/public_html/demo/django/` and added additional virtual host configuration at the end of the existing virtual host config for `www.ourdomain.com` by loading external config file. There was no errors in config file. Apache restarted successfully. PHP projects are running fine.

This is a part of the main apache conf file of our main domain `www.ourdomain.com`

```
<VirtualHost ipaddress:80>
    ServerName ourdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.ourdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html
    ServerAdmin webmaster@ourdomain.com
    UseCanonicalName Off

    # configuration to load modules 

    # To customize this VirtualHost use an include file at the following location
    Include "/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/user/ourdomain.com/*.conf"
</VirtualHost>
```

I've added a conf file at `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/std/2_4/user/ourdomain.com/` which includes

```
    Alias /demo/django/static /home/user/public_html/demo/django/static
    <Directory /home/user/public_html/demo/django/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /demo/django/media /home/user/public_html/demo/django/media
    <Directory /home/user/public_html/demo/django/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/public_html/demo/django/testproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess testdjango python-path=/home/user/public_html/demo/django python-home=/home/user/public_html/demo/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup testdjango
    WSGIScriptAlias /demo/django /home/user/public_html/demo/django/testproject/wsgi.py
```

Checked if mod_wsgi is loaded

```
# sudo /usr/sbin/httpd -M
[sudo] password for user:
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 ...
 suphp_module (shared)
 wsgi_module (shared)
 passenger_module (shared)
#
```

When I try to access `http://ourdomain.com/demo/django` with this configuration **Gateway Timeout** error is showing.

```
# error_log
[Fri Jul 10 14:19:21.342208 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 3083:tid 47072565069568] [client *.*.*.*:*] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'django': /home/user/public_html/demo/django/testproject/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this for future reference for anyone who comes across this *

Later when I checked and found out that the static files were being served and only the pages could not be loaded.
The old configuration had problems in `WSGIDaemonProcess`. `python-home` and `python-path` values were not correct. Further reading [docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html) in `WSGIDaemonProcess` section I changed the values according. After some trail and error I was able to run the app. This is not complete. Need to work on reloading app updates.

While playing around the config, **Internal Server Error** occured when I changed `WSGIDaemonProcess testdjango python-path=/home/user/public_html/demo/django python-home=/home/user/public_html/demo/django/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages` to `WSGIDaemonProcess testdjango python-path=/home/user/public_html/demo/django python-home=/home/user/public_html/demo/django/venv`.

From [docs](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html) in `WSGIDaemonProcess` section

> **python-home=directory**
> Set the location of the Python virtual environment to be used by the daemon processes. The directory to use is that which `sys.prefix` is set to for the Python virtual environment. The virtual environment can have been created by `virtualenv`, `pyvenv` or `python -m venv`.
> Note that the Python virtual environment must have been created using the same base Python version as was used to compile the mod_wsgi module. You can’t use this to force mod_wsgi to somehow use a different Python version than it was compiled for. If you want to use a different version of Python, you will need to reinstall mod_wsgi, compiling it for the version you want. It is not possible for the one mod_wsgi instance to run applications for both Python 2 and 3 at the same time.

> **python-path=directory | python-path=directory:directory**
> List of colon separated directories to add to the Python module search path, ie., `sys.path`.
> Note that this is not strictly the same as having set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable when running normal command line Python. When this option is used, the directories are added by calling `site.addsitedir()`. As well as adding the directory to `sys.path` this function has the effect of opening and interpreting any `.pth` files located in the specified directories.
> If using a Python virtual environment, rather than use this option to refer to the `site-packages` directory of the Python virtual environment, you should use the `python-home` option to specify the root of the Python virtual environment instead.
> In all cases, if the directory contains Python packages which have C extension components, those packages must have been installed using the same base Python version as was used to compile the mod_wsgi module. You should not mix packages from different Python versions or installations.

Environment:

- Apache/2.4.43
- mod_wsgi/4.7.1
- Python/3.6
- Django/3.0.8

---

The current config on which the Django app runs

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess ourdomain.com python-home=/home/user/public_html/demo/django/venv python-path=/home/user/public_html/demo/django/
    WSGIProcessGroup ourdomain.com

    Alias /demo/django/media /home/user/public_html/demo/django/media
    <Directory /home/user/public_html/demo/django/media>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

    Alias /demo/django/static /home/user/public_html/demo/django/static
    <Directory /home/user/public_html/demo/django/static>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/public_html/demo/django/testproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            <IfVersion < 2.4>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
            </IfVersion>
            <IfVersion >= 2.4>
                Require all granted
            </IfVersion>
        </Files>
    </Directory>


    WSGIScriptAlias /demo/django /home/user/public_html/demo/django/testproject/wsgi.py

    <Directory /home/user/public_html/demo/django>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
            Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
    </Directory>
```