# Trying to deploy Django on SiteGround

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy a Django app on Siteground through SSH. I have transferred all the files through Filezilla. Everything is setup.

I have developed several apps on AWS using ubuntu. But in siteground Fedora OS is provided in SSH, I am not familiar with that much. I can't have superuser privileges.

Running my Django server on port 8000:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Host name is already added in ALLOWED_HOST of setting.py:

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["himeshp7.sg-host.com","*"]

The server is running in SSH, but I am unable to open my web app on the browser. In AWS we get the option to enable ports in Security Groups, but I couldn't find anything like that on Siteground, I also talked with customer care but they are telling to upgrade, I still doubt that if it will work or not after that as I couldn't find anything proper for deploying Django on Siteground.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your server ip address to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and do `python manage.py runserver <your_server_ip_address>:8000` to simply run your app in Debug mode. (Replace <your_server_ip_address>). You can then access your app over port 8000

To host your app in production you need to do further more than running the app through command like installing WSGI HTTP Server, configuring to run your app on port 80 or some other port, etc.

Amazon AWS has UI for most of the things so that you could easily enable ports and such other things. This is not the case of other hosting providers.

Unless you don't have the sudo privileges there are no options to run Django app in shared hosting. Hosting providers that gives SSH/terminal access for shared hosting will not give sudo privileges for security reasons. You should be having a VPS/Dedicated account for that which costs higher to have higher control over your server.

**Why do I need sudo privileges ?**

- You may need to install additional packages/dependencies.
- To add additional apache/nginx config for your domain. etc

Otherwise you can go for hosting providers where they provide additonal "Setup Python App" in "Software" section in CPanel for their Shared Hosting Plans. You don't need to worry about server configuration. [image]
There are many providers that gives this option in their Shared Hosting. Two of such providers that I know of:

- namecheap [refer](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10048/2182/how-to-work-with-python-app)
- a2hosting [refer](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/installing-and-configuring-django-on-linux-shared-hosting?currencycode=INR&_ga=2.246631492.1145949866.1598253411-242562638.1598253411)

*Based on the exp that I had on deploying python app on Hostgator VPS [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62842086/django-deployment-in-hostgator-vps-php-and-python-on-same-server-easyapache2).*

Comment: Ok. I will try with CPanel.